# Where is my code when running under IOS simulator?

Tags: ios

I would like to know where is my app file located when running under simulator?

It is a temp folder, but where is it?

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what you mean by code? Code remains where ever it is. Are you looking for the binary thats run on the simulator?

Comment: Are you looking for `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications are installed here:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<version>/Applications
```

Answer (score 2):

Your app files and stuff are located in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications
```

Where `7.0` can be replaced by the version you are running on.